# An example of threefold

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, toric-varieties

Its description is a little bit complicated but it would be great if anyone can give an example.
I tried to construct it as a toric variety (See the [previous question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/200339/an-example-of-toric-threefold)) but did not succeed.

I am looking for a projective threefold $X$ with $H^1(\mathcal O_X) = 0$ such that it has only three ordinary double points $p_1, p_2, p_3$ as its singularities.
Its anticanonical divisor $-K_X$ is linearly equivalent to 
$$Y_{12}^1 + Y_{23}^1 + Y_{31}^1 + Y_{12}^2 + Y_{23}^2 + Y_{31}^2,$$

where $Y_{ij}^k$'s are divisors of $X$,  isomorphic to $\mathbb P^2$. Each $Y_{ij}^k$ goes through $p_i, p_j$.
The [triangular bipyramid](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/90/Hexahedron5.svg/100px-Hexahedron5.svg.png)  (click the word for its image) can describe how  $Y_{ij}^k$'s intersect with another.
The faces of the triangular bipyramid corresponds to $Y_{ij}^k$'s. The edges describe how $Y_{ij}^k$'s intersects. 
If two of $Y_{ij}^k$'s intersect, then they intersect transversely along a line of degree one.
Note that vertices of valence 4 correspond to the points $p_1, p_2, p_3$.  For fixed $k$, $Y_{12}^k, Y_{23}^k, Y_{31}^k$ meet at a point, corresponding to each of the other two vertices.

To Prof. Lev Borisov (if you take a look at this post):
In the [previous post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/200339/an-example-of-toric-threefold), you suggested that I presumably can make it as a toric DM stack. 
I know little about toric DM stack but I would like to ask if such 'a toric DM stack' would have the above properties.

Thanks for your attention.